# How to fetch name value for Corresponding code of json in php

Tags: php, json

I have Following Value :-

What i want :- I want to fetch City name from City code ?

For example :- if input is "BA", i want to display "Bagmati", if input is "DH", i want to display "Dhawlagiri"

```
$value = '{"NP":{
"1" : {"code":"BA","name":"Bagmati"},
"2" : {"code":"BH","name":"Bheri"},
"3" : {"code":"DH","name":"Dhawalagiri"},
"4" : {"code":"GA","name":"Gandaki"},
"5" : {"code":"JA","name":"Janakpur"},
"6" : {"code":"KA","name":"Karnali"},
"7" : {"code":"KO","name":"Kosi"},
"8" : {"code":"LU","name":"Lumbini"},
"9" : {"code":"MA","name":"Mahakali"},
"10" : {"code":"ME","name":"Mechi"},
"11" : {"code":"NA","name":"Narayani"},
"12" : {"code":"RA","name":"Rapti"},
"13" : {"code":"SA","name":"Sagarmatha"},
"14" : {"code":"SE","name":"Seti"}
}';
```

What i tried in `PHP` :-

```
$value = json_decode($json);
//print_r($value);

foreach ($value->IN->code as $city) {
    echo $city->name;
}
```

But I am not sure, how can i get this. any help will be appreciated.

Just for note, i took these value from `javascript` file :-
state.js file

```
"NP":{
"1" : {"code":"BA","name":"Bagmati"},
"2" : {"code":"BH","name":"Bheri"},
"3" : {"code":"DH","name":"Dhawalagiri"},
"4" : {"code":"GA","name":"Gandaki"},
"5" : {"code":"JA","name":"Janakpur"},
"6" : {"code":"KA","name":"Karnali"},
"7" : {"code":"KO","name":"Kosi"},
"8" : {"code":"LU","name":"Lumbini"},
"9" : {"code":"MA","name":"Mahakali"},
"10" : {"code":"ME","name":"Mechi"},
"11" : {"code":"NA","name":"Narayani"},
"12" : {"code":"RA","name":"Rapti"},
"13" : {"code":"SA","name":"Sagarmatha"},
"14" : {"code":"SE","name":"Seti"}
},
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will decode your json to native php arrays instead of combination of arrays and objects, and you have only to iterate `$value["NP"]` array,

```
$value = json_decode($json,1);

foreach ($value["NP"] as $el) {
    echo $el["name"];
}
```

Comment: Where does this answer test whether the code matches the input?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$assoc` argument to `json_decode()` to get an associative array instead of objects:

```
$value = json_decode($json, true);
```

Then you can iterate through it:

```
foreach ($value['NP'] as $subarray) {
    if ($subarray['code'] == $input) {
        echo $subarray['name'];
        break;
    }
}
```